# How do I create the a web form which is always visible in the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, invisible

Please have a look at the following page:

http://www.eddale.co/general/on-reception-the-iphone-4-hysteria-the-real-lifelab-test-conundrum

I want to create a similar form like the one always sticking to the bottom of the page in the link above ...

how do i do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about support for IE6 you can position it fixed at the bottom with css e.g

```
#element_to_position {position: fixed; left:0;bottom:0;width:100%;height:20px;}
```

If you care you must tweak it with a fake body tag. E.g. see this http://ryanfait.com/position-fixed-ie6/

Answer (score 0):

This should get it sticking:

http://www.zymic.com/tutorials/html/effective-footers/

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using...oter-code.html

http://css-tricks.com/sticky-footer/

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/cro...sticky-footer/

http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer...ottom-of-page/ (Direct Link)

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/k...om-of-the-page